# No such file or directory while using Vina Dongky template

Tags: php, templates, extensions, virtuemart, joomla-3.9

I am using a template called Vina Dongky for VirtueMart content and I'm getting some errors.

> Warning:
> require_once(/home/priskork/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/priskork/public_html/templates/vina_dongky/error.php on line 28
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/home/priskork/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php'
> (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')
> in /home/priskork/public_html/templates/vina_dongky/error.php on line
> 28

Comment: This is a commercial template. Assuming you purchased the template through official channels, you should contact the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your using a rockettheme gantry 4 template, the head renderer is already loaded (as of version joomla 3.7? several years ago in any case) now, and the included file is gone so just comment out the line in both error.php and offline.php

Alternatively you can check for the class so the template would still work in old Joomla if that's a thing.

```
if (!class_exists('JDocumentRendererHead')) {
    require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php');
}
```